# Android no value for php response

Tags: java, php, android

So I am trying to connect the database running on the server with the android app. While trying to fix this I stumbled on some strange error that says:  no value for succes. This is kinda strange since I did declare it in the php by saying: $response["success"] = true. I'm starting to run out of options so that's why I came here to ask this question. Please someone release me from my suffering.

The Error:

```
W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for success
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:389)
                  at org.json.JSONObject.getBoolean(JSONObject.java:410)
W/System.err:     at rugenbrink.geordi.eftelingattractioncounter.RegisterActivity$1$1.onResponse(RegisterActivity.java:48)
              at rugenbrink.geordi.eftelingattractioncounter.RegisterActivity$1$1.onResponse(RegisterActivity.java:43)
W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60)
              at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
              at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

The PHP code:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("host", "user", "password", "database");

$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$emailadress = $_POST["emailadress"];
$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO user (username, password, emailadress) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "sss", $username, $password, $emailadress);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

$response = array();
$response["success"] = true;  

echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

The java code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    final EditText etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.usernameRegister);
    final EditText etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordRegister);
    final EditText etEmailadress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailadress);

    final Button bRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.registerButton);

    bRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            final String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
            final String password = etPassword.getText().toString();
            final String emailadress = etEmailadress.getText().toString();

            Response.Listener<String> responsListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response.substring(response.indexOf("{"), response.lastIndexOf("}") + 1));
                        boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                        if(success){
                            Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginFrag.class);
                            RegisterActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                        } else{
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterActivity.this);
                            builder.setMessage("Register failed!")
                                    .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                    .create()
                                    .show();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };

            RegisterRequest registerRequest = new RegisterRequest(username, password, emailadress, responsListener);
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(RegisterActivity.this);
            queue.add(registerRequest);
        }
    });
```

The RegisterRequest:

```
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class RegisterRequest extends StringRequest {

private static final String REGISTER_REQUEST_URL = "https://XXX.000webhost.com/Register.php";
private Map<String, String> params;

public RegisterRequest(String username, String password, String emailadress, Response.Listener<String> listener){
    super(Method.POST, REGISTER_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
    params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("username", username);
    params.put("password", password);
    params.put("emailadress", emailadress);
}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getParams(){
    return params;
    }
}
```

I hope you can help me, thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you log what you get as response?

Comment: @Juan I've added the logs to the post

Comment: @Barns I've added hte logs to the post

Comment: In  public void onResponse(String response) log the value of the response variable. (Log.d(TAG,response);) to see what is returned by the server.

Comment: Then you are querying the the wrong URL, because this is not JSON and certainly not what your PHP code should return

Comment: @Juan that's what I did

Comment: Well what you are getting as response is not what the php code you poseted generates.

Comment: @Barns hmm okay, I can try a different URL and log that response, but first I'm gonna have some diner. I will update you on the results

Comment: @Barns okay so the problem was that i used http instead of https in the link to my server. But now my code won't even reach the onResponse method. Do you have any idea what that could be?

Comment: Could you show me what your URL looks like? You can replace your domain with XXX. It should look like `http://www.example.com/mypath/myscript.php`

Comment: @Barns https://XXX.000webhost.com/Register.php you mean like this?

Comment: @Barns I added an error listener and this is the error message I'm getting: D/Error: com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused.

Comment: Is this a subdomain? If yes than this post might help :: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39810487/com-android-volley-noconnectionerror-java-net-unknownhostexception

Comment: I am also not seeing where you set the `JsonObjectRequest getRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(...)` Which is where the URL would be passed as a parameter